# What is better performance wise for console log usage

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, logging, console.log

I am planning on redoing all my errors in nodejs file to make them more useful, so I can see what is going on.

Therefore I was planning on taking it from this:

```
console.log("Example err:", err)
```

and switching it to a function that is called outside which calls console.log() like so:

```
const app_type = {
    database: "log_database",
    server: "log_server",
    third_party: "log_third_party"
}

const error_api = {
    modular: "modular"
}

const error_function = {
    getUser: "getUser",

}
function createLogMsg(appCode, errorApi, errorFunction, errorMsg, errorStack, userId, queryType, statusCode) {
 console.log(appCode, errorApi, errorFunction, errorMsg, errorStack, userId, queryType, statusCode);
}
```

and from inside another function:

```
createLogMsg(app_type.database, error_api.modular, error_function.getUser, "Error getting mysql_pool connection ", "", "", "", "");
```

I am wondering if there is a performance cost for switching it to the new function method with the look ups? Significant enough to impact a large user base using it?

I don't know how to print ms of console.log print out to test performance either. If someone can help with answering above or telling me how to check performance time on console log difference, appreciate it.

Comment: For measuring performance use [`hrtime`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_hrtime_time). The rest is just opinion based and not really suited for SO

Comment: Why would this be opinion based? Is there no way to tell if a function with arguements before a console is called is better or worse than straight console log

Comment: Define `better` or `worse`... what's the measure?

Comment: Longer time to produce the console log hence slowing down when the next operation occurs